# Generate string with leading 0 if number is less than 3 digit otherwise the number itself

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a string with leading 0 if the given number is less than 3 digit. if 3 or more digit the number should show as it is.

The way Im trying is as follows

```
declare @id int;
set @id=13;
select right('000',cast(@id as varchar(3)),3)
```

it result **013** which works correct.

For 3 digit or less its working fine. But if we supply `@id` as 1234 it results 234, where 1234 we need to get

So how can we make that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SQL 2012 or higher, you can use [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @id int = 13;
SELECT FORMAT(@id, '000');
```

Comment: Heads up: [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Good to know. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 4):

Just another option if 2012+

```
Select format(  12,'000')   -- 012
      ,format( 123,'000')   -- 123
      ,format(1234,'000')   -- 1234
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `case` is the simplest solution:

```
declare @id int;

set @id = 13;

select (case when @id < 1000 then right('000', cast(@id as varchar(10)), 3)
             else cast(@id as varchar(10))
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of CASE, len, and LEFT:

```
DECLARE @myval int = 7

SELECT CASE WHEN @myval > 999
             THEN CAST(@myval as varchar)
             ELSE LEFT('000', 3 - len(CAST(@myval as varchar))) + CAST(@myval as varchar)
       END AS myString
```